# Gitlab CI can't fetch repo because keep asking for keychain password

Tags: macos, gitlab, keychain, gitlab-ci

I have project on company Gitlab. Project is for iOS platform so my node for building project is Mac Mini with OS Sierra.

Runner works great - connecting etc works. But when I try to run pipeline I get message on node like on picture. This alert appear when gitlab runner wants to checkout code.

I checked in KeychainAccess that **git-credential-osxkeychain** app have access to password for gitlab on **login** keychain.

How to fix that and disable dialog for keychain password?

config.toml file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
name = "Mac mini runner"
url = "URLtoMyGitLab"
token = "token"
executor = "shell"
[runners.cache]
```

[image: git-credential-osxkeychain]

Comment: You get a popup window when trying to run a pipeline? I'm pretty sure you need to provide more info as your local popups have nothing to do with gitlab and it's runners.

Comment: Yes I get popup on my mac mini node when gitlab runner tried to checkout code. Then when I provide password to my keychain it clone repo and run other scrips from config file. What additional info can be useful?

Comment: Well, the runner configuration. What executor you are running etc.

Comment: In previous message I attached my  runner configuration (without token and url). I am using shell as executor

Comment: I believe if you switch to docker executor it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because iOS project requires Xcode tools for building which is not available on any docker image.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution for this was to configure git, to use keychain in the project root.

```
- git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

along with unlocking the keychain in `before_script:`

```
- security unlock-keychain -p $PASSWORD /Users/[MASKED]/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
- security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l /Users/[MASKED]/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```